# Проверка установленой картинки

Tags: java, android

Как проверить if блоком, какая картинка установлена.
Есть 2 кнопки. Каждая из них переносит одно и тоже окно. После переадресции устанавливаются разные картинки. Мне нужно проверить по картинкам, то есть какая из 2 картинок установлена и после это подставлять определенный textview. Мне нужно проверять по картинкам, просто код специфичен и нужно только подставлять элементы через проверку по картинке

Comment: слева должно быть BitmapDrawbale а уже оттуда можно получить Bitmap и сравнивать ссылки, чтобы это корректно работало естественно ссылки нужно хранить и устанавливать Bitmap в ImageView через них

Comment: @Style-7, можно пример проверки? я понял как объявить переменную, а логику проверки не понял

Comment: if( bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() == bitmaps[ i ] ){}, не ясна задача где это может понадобится

Comment: @Style-7, а зачем массив?

Comment: как я понял у вас есть несколько картинок и вы по ходу что-то меняете в ImageView так?

Comment: @Style-7, перечитайте, я уточнил начало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_java);
```

Попробуй так

Update, проверка на картинку:

```java
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_java);
imageView.setTag("drawable"+":"+R.drawable.ic_java);
if (imageView.getTag() != null && imageView.getTag() instanceof String && ((String) imageView.getTag()).contains("drawable:")) {
    int drawableID = Integer.parseInt(((String) imageView.getTag()).split(":")[1]);
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: А можно ещё проверку на установленный картинку. То есть какая картинка установлена, то что-то делает?

Comment: Изменил ответ, посмотри